# Configure log4j xml file for sending e-mail when an error has encountered in my java application

Tags: log4j

I have configured the log4j xml to send e-mail when an error encounters in my application, but still i could not get any mails.Could you please suggest me if i have to do something else other than this configuration.Below is the configuration done in xml file for e-mails

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="true">
<appender name="XMPAYROLAppender"
        class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="log/XMPAYROLLogger.log" />
        <param name="datePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
        <param name="append" value="true" />
        <param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %C{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="AdministratorEmail" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
  <param name="BufferSize" value="1024" />
  <param name="SMTPHost" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
  <param name="From" value="kiran98373@gmail.com" />
  <param name="To" value="kiran98373@gmail.com.com" />
  <param name="Subject" value="test mail" />
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern"
      value="[%d{ISO8601}]%n%n%-5p%n%n%c%n%n%m%n%n" />
  </layout>
  <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
    <param name="LevelMin" value="error" />
    <param name="LevelMax" value="fatal" />
  </filter>
</appender>

<logger name="XMPAYROLLogger" additivity="true">
        <level class="org.apache.log4j.Level" value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="XMPAYROLAppender" />
</logger>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a few things.

First, your "to" address is `kiran98373@gmail.com.com`. Is that your true destination address? `.com.com`? Nice.

Second, you're using Google's SMTP server to send an email, with no extra configuration. You're going to need much more configuration than that. For once, Google doesn't accept anything on the standard SMTP port. They also require (I'm pretty confident about that) SSL connectivity.

The default SMTP configuration isn't going to do. To see exactly what your problem is, turn on the `SMTPDebug` flag:

`<param name="SMTPDebug" value="true" />`